# Проблема с @dp.message

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Делаю простенький калькулятор. После /start пользователю дается выбор из двух inline кнопок, выбрав любую он должен написать число, а бот в ответ выдаст расчет. Проблема в том, что в независимости от выбора кнопки, отрабатывает верхний @dp.message(), при добавлении F по data кнопки ничего не происходит вообще. Помогите разобраться, спасибо

```
    @dp.callback_query(F.data == 'big_button_1')
    async def process_button_1_press(callback: CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, f'Введите сумму в RUB')

        @dp.message()
        async def rubcny(msg: types.Message):
            me = msg.text
            await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, f"формула")


    @dp.callback_query(F.data == 'big_button_2')
    async def process_button_1_press(callback: CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, 'Введите сумму в USD')

        @dp.message()
        async def usdtcny(msg: types.Message):
            me1 = msg.text
            await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, f"формула")
```